# calling a view controller without pushing its view

Tags: objective-c, ios4

Having 3 views view1,view2,view3

```
From view1 there is a function which calls view2
{
view2* view2Controller =[[view2 alloc]initWithNibName:@"view2" bundle:nil];       
        [ view2Controller SessionMaintained];
      //  [self.navigationController pushViewController:view2Controller animated:YES]; 
}

now in view 2 call is made to view3
{
view3* view3Controller =[[view3 alloc]initWithNibName:@"view3" bundle:nil];       
        [ view3Controller SessionMaintained];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:view3Controller animated:YES]; 
}
```

now i want to push view3 directly without pushing view2

Comment: want to go to  view3 without loading its view2 from view1

Comment: Maybe it's easier to use Delegates if you need some kind of communication between your ViewControllers

Answer (score 0):

Whats the problem in directly creating the View3 object and push in View1 ?

Comment: have sum dependencies in view 2 based on the processing result vil launch view3 but view2 shdnt get launched

Answer (score 0):

So I am making answer with your question itself

From view1 there is a function which calls view2

```
{
view2* view2Controller =[[view2 alloc]initWithNibName:@"view2" bundle:nil];       
        [ view2Controller SessionMaintained];
//push view2 w/o animation
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:view2Controller animated:NO]; 
//call some method (say showView3) in view2
        [view2Controller showView3];
        [view2Controller release];
}
```

now in view 2 (showView3 method), call is made to view3

```
{
view3* view3Controller =[[view3 alloc]initWithNibName:@"view3" bundle:nil];       
        [ view3Controller SessionMaintained];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:view3Controller animated:YES]; 
}
```